# Optimizing MySql Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi is there any way of optimizing this mysql query ?

```
SELECT ADDRESS , D_ADDRESS , U_DATA 
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1 
WHERE (ADDRESS LIKE '0010') OR 
(ADDRESS LIKE 'DHIL') OR 
(ADDRESS LIKE 'FINN') OR 
(ADDRESS LIKE 'GRWL') OR 
(ADDRESS LIKE 'JNOD') OR 
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not using any wildcards in the selection criteria, all like comparisons mean equal. Therefore you can use the in() operator instead of the ORs:

```
SELECT ADDRESS , D_ADDRESS , U_DATA 
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1 
WHERE ADDRESS IN ('0010', 'DHIL', ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

try [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) e.g

```
WHERE ADDRESS REGEXP '(0010)|(DHIL)|(..)'
```

involves only one test which is faster

Also if you want just accurate matches you may employ the [`FIELD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) MySQL function like:

```
WHERE FIELD(ADDRESS,'0010|DHIL|..') > 0
```

or even

```
WHERE FIELD(ADDRESS,'0010','DHIL','..') > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create additional table with column `search` of type `CHAR(4)` and fill it will all search values: `0010`, `DHIL`, ...
2. Run query:

   `SELECT ADDRESS , D_ADDRESS , U_DATA
     FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1 
       WHERE ADDRESS IN (SELECT search FROM search_table)`

or

```
SELECT t.ADDRESS, t.D_ADDRESS, t.U_DATA
  FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1 t JOIN search_table s ON t.ADDRESS=s.search
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `in` and create an appropriate index.  The `in` version (as in other answers) looks like:

```
SELECT ADDRESS , D_ADDRESS , U_DATA 
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1 
WHERE ADDRESS IN ('0010', . . .)
```

The index you want is:

```
create index idx_table1_address on table1(address);
```

It is the index that will give the bigger boost performance, if the optimizer decides that it is useful.  However, MySQL does optimize `in` with a list of constants by sorting the list and doing a binary search.

Comment: How can i sure the above options with wild card %